# Freezing point depression and organic molecules

Tags: water, phase

Do organic molecules reduce the freezing point of water in the same way that inorganic salts do?  I've recently been swimming in lakes with a high organic content (e.g. mostly tannins.  There's a lake in this area called Tea Lake).  I've got an infra-red thermometer and readings taken from the water at this time of year before total freeze up have been around -1 to -2 degrees C.  Are these reasonable (accepting of course possible inaccuracies and calibration issues with the thermometer)?
Thanks,
Phil

Comment: More likely there's *some* dissolved salt(s), though high concentrations of organic compounds certainly *do* depress freezing point, e.g. sugar-water sherbet or "ices".

Comment: Alcohol, an organic molecule, does just fine.

Comment: When using an IR thermometer you must be very careful when you choose the emissivity parameter that changes the measurement value a lot. Also water is a very reflective medium due to its high dielectric constant and you should be even more careful with your results as the heat your body emits can be reflected as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a freezing point depression of $\pu{−1.86 °C},$ the solution should be made by adding $\pu{1 mol}$ organic substance to $\pu{1 L}$ water. And $\pu{1 mol}$ per liter is much. For glucose, it is $\pu{180 g}$ per liter. It is nearly a syrup. I doubt your lake has such a high concentration whatever the nature of the solute.

For salts, it is less, because usual salts are made of two ions. For example, $\pu{29 g}$ $\ce{NaCl}$ in $\pu{1 L}$ water is enough to get a freezing point depression of $\pu{−1.86 °C}.$ Anyway, $\pu{29 g}$ salt added to one liter is not negligible. Are you sure of your measurements?

Comment: I'm not sure at all of the measurements (this IR thermometer is a crude tool and not designed for water) but I was just interested in the possibility that the lake water was lower than 0 degrees C before freezing.  I'll bring a better thermometer next time.   The main question was whether organic molecules reduce freezing point to the same extent that inorganic salts do.  From your answer I suspect my measurements are not accurate and that the water temperature was not that far below zero.  (My understanding of this is based upon high school chemistry from many years ago).

Comment: @Maurice Please format physical quantities appropriately. `\pu{…}` macro can help you with that. For example, instead of `$180g$` $(180g),$ which implies $g$ is a *variable* (variables are typed in italics), use `$\pu{180 g}$` $(\pu{180 g})$ for proper spacing and upright unit symbol. Also, try to avoid asking OP questions in the answer. If you need clarifications, sort it out in the comments.

Comment: @andselink I have still typography related doubts, if I should format short things like 180 g or 1 mol by pu{} in free text (as examples of many similar cases). In numerical formula it is clear I should, but in free text it often makes visual disturbance due different and bigger font. If left as it is, it looks more naturally.

Comment: @Poutnik You are correct, 180 g and −1.86 °C would make even more sense in this particular case (just make sure that a minus is used, not en dash), but since the original post already used MathJax for everything, so I used it as a basis for editing.